# The definition of key default value by keyval package

Tags: key-value

For a key `keya` defined by

```
\define@key{fam}{keya}[\def\y#1{#1}]{\def\x##1{##1x#1}}
```

the *keyval* package uses

```
\def\KV@def#1#2[#3]#4{%
  \begingroup\toks@{#3}%
  \xdef\@gtempa{\expandafter\noexpand\csname KV@#1@#2\endcsname{\the\toks@}}%
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\let\csname KV@#1@#2@default\endcsname\@gtempa
  \expandafter\def\csname KV@#1@#2\endcsname##1{#4}%
}
```

to define the default value as

```
\KV@fam@keya@default{\KV@fam@keya{defau}}
```

This style of defining the default value is called *the standard format* by the *xkeyval* package. Packages such *fancyvrb* don't adhere to this standard. The *xkeyval* package says that such packages *abuse* the default-value format.

I have always wondered why the *keyval* package chose to define the default value of a key in this way, instead of the apparently cheaper approach of storing the default value in a macro like

```
\def\KV@fam@keya@default{defau}
```

Without eTeX this should actually be

```
\newtoks\toksa
\toksa{defau}
\edef\KV@fam@keya@default{\the\toksa}
```

or something similar.

Comment: Where is the question? Why don't you accept any of your questions.

Comment: Where is the question? Wait for David Carlisle! Please I have clicked on the 'accept' mark/button but the red warning will not disappear.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: Be sure to not to close the page too early after clicking (give it a few seconds). If you have JavaScript disabled or blocked, enable it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Why" answers are always hard to answer, especially decades after the fact. I think that the original motivating examples that I was trying to pull into a common key-value system included cases where the "default" action didn't correspond directly to passing a value to a key, invoking a separate ..@default command name means that the default case can be defined to do essentially anything.

Comment: David: Thanks. This rather trivial question has led me to something in *ltxkeys* package.